# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter paggination on recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase

I wanted paggination with `RecyclerView` using firebase real data base not firestone. With `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which is provided my google.So RecyclerView is reverse order so because of that top is at the bottom.Need to load 5 item each time when user reach top of the list .

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private TextView username;
private TextView post;
private AdapterComment adapterComment;
private ArrayList<Comment> commentArrayList;
public static String GetAllFeed = "";
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager, mDetailLayoutManager;

private Dialog dialog, detailDialog;
// [START define_database_reference]
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// [END define_database_reference]

RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
//Solution for descending list on refresh
private int pastVisibleItems;
private int visibleItemCount;
private int totalItemCount,visibleLast;

AdapterImage adapterImage;
ArrayList arrayList;
ValueEventListener postListener, notifyListener;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> mAdapter;
float screenX;
int posSet = 0, showNotification = 0,mLastKey=0;
Query postsQuery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    GetAllFeed = FeedHelper.NODE_FEED;

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    post = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (AppClass.isInternetConnected()) {
        //use to set the user name with two different text and size
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        String s = Utility.getSharedPreferenceString(MainActivity.this, Constants.FirstName) + " " +
                Utility.getSharedPreferenceString(MainActivity.this, Constants.LastName);
        String s1 = " " + getString(R.string.log_in);

        SpannableString span1 = new SpannableString(s);
        span1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1f), 0, s.length(), 0); // set size
        span1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor)), 0, s.length(), 0);// set color
        builder.append(span1);
        SpannableString span2 = new SpannableString(s1);

        span2.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.6f), 0, s1.length(), 0); // set size
        span2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor1)), 0, s1.length(), 0);// set color
        builder.append(span2);

        username.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        AppClass.getAppinstance().showLoadingDialog(MainActivity.this);
        getData();
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                Log.d("newState", "" + newState);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisibleItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();


                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    visibleLast = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (AppClass.isInternetConnected()) {
                     getData();
                    } else {
                        AppClass.getAppinstance().showToast(getString(R.string.internet));
                    }




                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        AppClass.getAppinstance().showToast(getString(R.string.internet));
    }

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }


}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }


}

public void getData() {

    if (mLastKey==0) {
        postsQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(GetAllFeed).orderByKey().
                limitToLast(6);
    }else {
        postsQuery =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(GetAllFeed).orderByKey().
                endAt(mLastKey).limitToLast(7);

    }
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
            .setQuery(postsQuery, Post.class)
            .build();

    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
            return new PostViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final int position, final Post model) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);      
          viewHolder.titleView.setText(model.lastName);

        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    notifyListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mLastKey= Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            if (showNotification == 0) {
                showNotification = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            } else if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > showNotification) {
                showNotification = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Snackbar.make(mRecyclerView, "New post available to see post click on Top.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Top", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1, 0);

                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message

            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    postsQuery.addValueEventListener(notifyListener);
    AppClass.getAppinstance().dismissLoadingDialog();
}

       }
```

Comment: I cannot see something in your code related to pagination, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried but above code is not the code which I am trying ...I serach online and have't find anything related to paggination with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: You should add the code that you using, to see what the problem is.

Comment: Okay done now you can check above code

Comment: When scrolling, you aren't using a new query. There is nothing there that can help you with that.

Comment: getData();  In which I am using the query with condition and get data call when scrolling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188113/discussion-between-avadhesh-mourya-and-alex-mamo).